# How to extract value from a string in XML response using karate

Tags: dsl, karate

Unfortunately the respons ei am getting from my backend is not in correct xml format and it's giving the response in a bad format like this:

```
<soapenv:Body>

    <ns2:getInputResponse xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasisopen.org/ns/bpel4people/ws-humantask/api/200803">

        <ns2:taskData xmlns:s186="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:s187="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" s186:type="s187:string">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

&lt;SubscriptionApprovalData xmlns="http://workflow.subscription.apimgt.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

     &lt;apiName>Auto_Approval&lt;/apiName>

     &lt;apiVersion>v1&lt;/apiVersion>

     &lt;apiContext>/test/lambda/v1&lt;/apiContext>

     &lt;apiProvider>admin&lt;/apiProvider>

     &lt;subscriber>regtest&lt;/subscriber>

     &lt;applicationName>newApp&lt;/applicationName>

     &lt;tierName>Gold&lt;/tierName>

     &lt;workflowExternalRef&gt;23d30bd8-51e3-4afe-aae0-3fa159d85a6b&lt;/workflowExternalRef>

     &lt;callBackURL>https://apistore-dev-dev-a878-14-ams10-nonp.qcpaws.qantas.com.au/services/WorkflowCallbackService&lt;/callBackURL>
  &lt;/SubscriptionApprovalData></ns2:taskData>

    </ns2:getInputResponse>

</soapenv:Body>
```

Now because of this Karate is not able to read the response and fetch the value of "workflowExternalRef" which is my goal for this test.

Is there any way karate can read it?

Comment: Can karate do xml decode/encode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really messed up XML so please check with someone in your team if this can be fixed.

Anyway, since you can use Java in Karate, here is one way to do this. This is not production-quality code, please adapt as appropriate:

```
* string response = response
* def start = response.indexOf('workflowExternalRef&gt;')
* def ref = response.substring(start + 23)
* def end = ref.indexOf('&lt;')
* def ref = ref.substring(0, end)
* match ref == '23d30bd8-51e3-4afe-aae0-3fa159d85a6b'
```